# Вопрос кроссбраузерности jquery и javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется такой кусок кода:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){ // Не работает как положенно! В IE 6.0 работает должным образом, а в Google Chrome редиректит на basket.php вместо index.php
      $("button#continue").click(function(){ // нажатие на кнопку Продолжить покупки
        window.location.href = "index.php";
      });
    });
</script>
```

Почему в IE 6.0 все работает как нужно (со страницы basket.php?id=9 редиректит на index.php при нажатии на кнопку Продолжить покупки), а в браузере Гугл Хром редирект проходит **неправильно** (со страницы basket.php?id=9 редиректит на **basket.php** при нажатии на кнопку Продолжить покупки). В других браузерах пока не проверял. Есть идеи почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Честно говоря, я удивлен что это вообще работает, хоть где-то. Правильно будет [так](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
   $(function (){
       $("#continue").click(function (evt/**$.Event*/){
           window.location.href = "index.php";
           evt.preventDefault();
       });
   });
```

Comment: При таких конструкциях тоже работает с глюком в Хроме (((

Comment: Причина явно не в этом, не в кавычках.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dmWgg/, вроде работает, но почему же тогда у меня в проекте глюк?

Comment: обновил ответ, попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь, этот вариант работает в обеих браузерах..